# How to put the url centered under the caption of a figure?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, captions, urls

I would like to put a source under the caption of my figure. The only thing that is not working is when I put the URL, the caption and the URL don't stay in the middle.
Also `\url{...}` didn't work by itself:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=70mm]{figure3}
\linespread{1}\caption{TITLE OF IMAGE
\\ \small{source by:\protect\url{www.aly-abbara.com/livre_gyn_obs/images/testosterone_DHT.html}}}
\label{figure3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

I took the liberty to format you post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 8):

If the source information must not follow possible modifications made beforehand to the caption layout, I agree with **Peter Grill**'s solution; however, I'd like to propose an alternative solution using the `caption*` command from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package; with this approach, the additional (unnumbered, unlisted) caption will also be sensible to modifications made to the caption layout.

Consider the following example: the first image shows that the source doesn't obey the 7cm width declared for captions; in the second image (using `\caption*`), the source will obey the 7cm modification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url}

\captionsetup[figure]{width=7cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=70mm]{figure3}
  \caption{TITLE OF IMAGE}
  \small source by:\url{www.aly-abbara.com/livre_gyn_obs/images/testosterone_DHT.html}
  \label{figure3} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=70mm]{figure3}
  \caption{TITLE OF IMAGE}
   \caption*{\small source by:\url{www.aly-abbara.com/livre_gyn_obs/images/testosterone_DHT.html}}
  \label{figure4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can place additional text outside of the `\caption`:

[image]

Also, as @GonzaloMedina pointed out, `\small` is a switch and does not take a parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=70mm]{figure3}
\linespread{1}
\caption{TITLE OF IMAGE}
 \small source by:\url{www.aly-abbara.com/livre_gyn_obs/images/testosterone_DHT.html}
\label{figure3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Peter's answer, but if you wanted to make the **URL, a part of the caption and into a hyperlink to a webpage,etc..**, you could do this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=Navy]{hyperref}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Technical 
        Illustrations/maxresdefault.jpg}
        \caption{Borderlands 2, Courtesy: \href{https://borderlands.com/en-US/} 
        {Borderlands 2}}
        \label{fig:borderlands}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here, I am using MikTex integrated into VS Code with Latex Workshop and a few other extensions...

[image: Clickable url-in-caption within VS Code's preview]

PS: I was in the middle of a project while searching for an answer similar to this and hence, the weird naming scheme and the picture